# Converting cartesian to polar double integral

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, area, polar-coordinates

[image]

> Convert the following integral to polar coordinates. You do not need to evaluate. $$\int_{-3}^3 \int_{x}^{\sqrt{9-x^2}} x^2y dy dx$$

My work :

I plotted the limits and I don't understand the bounded region due to $y=x$, but still I got like this which is wrong I know I solved the integral it should be $\frac{-81}{5}$ but the integral in the polar coordinates I obtained is incorrect 
$$  \int\limits_{\pi/4}^{\pi}\int\limits_{0}^{3}r^4\cos^2 \theta \sin \theta dr d\theta+ \int\limits_{\pi}^{5\pi/4}\int\limits_{-3/\cos \theta}^{-3\sqrt2}r^4\cos^2 \theta \sin \theta dr d\theta$$

**Can anyone help me recorrecting it the answer below is not complete, and it is definitely not the double of the answer** ???

Comment: From a sketch it appears that in polar coordinates you would be required to seperate the integral into $3$ sub integrals which add to the original integral.

Comment: Have you drawn the region? Seen what it actually looks like in the plane? That is usually _very_ helpful when converting integral bounds.

Comment: I have tried to correct some typos and also copy the text of the problem - so that it isn't included as a picture. Here is link to the [current revision](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/3696544/5). I am not really sure why the previous edit (of the same nature) was removed.

Comment: @learningstudent It's not just about grammar. (But even if it was, I do not really see why the edit was reverted.) Another thing, which you probably know by know, is that for several reasons including problem just as a picture is unsuitable. For example: [What should I do when I see a “pic-question”?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13677) and [other posts linked there](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/13677).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

The integration area is shaded  and their polar boundaries are marked in the graph. Moreover, in polar coordinates
$$x^2y dy dx= r^4\cos^2\theta\sin\theta drd\theta=f(r,\theta)drd\theta$$ and the integral is given as

$$\int_{\frac\pi4}^0 \int_3^{\frac3{\cos\theta}} f(r,\theta) drd\theta
+\int_{\frac\pi4}^{\pi} \int_0^{3} f(r,\theta)drd\theta  
+\int_{\pi}^{\frac{5\pi}4} \int_0^{-\frac3{\cos\theta}} f(r,\theta)drd\theta = - \frac{81}5
$$

Comment: A negative answer? You can tell the answer is positive by oddness in the region where $3\pi/4\le \theta\le 5\pi/4.$

Comment: let me know why it is $-3/cos\theta$  ? It should be plus !!

Comment: I got the same shaded graph as you get, but when I looked at the limits $x \le y \le \sqrt{9-x^2}$ , then later i thought we should not consider the right triangle extra region , because there we have $x>\sqrt{9-x^2}$

Comment: @learningstudent - because $\cos \theta < 0$ within the integration limits $\theta \in (\pi, 5\pi/4)$

Comment: Elaborate my above comment also ... about the inequality please

Comment: @learningstudent - note $\int_x^{\sqrt{9-x^2}} = -\int^x_{\sqrt{9-x^2}} $

Comment: ohhhhh so that is why u do pi/4 to 0    instead of 0 to pi/4

Comment: @learningstudent - that’s right

Answer (score 2):

Remark that $x\ge \sqrt{9-x^2}$ when $\frac 3{\sqrt 2}\le x\le 3$.

By a well-known theorem (see, for instance, [Fich, 596]), the given double integral is equal to $\int_{S} x^2y dx dy-\int_{S’} x^2y dx dy $, where $$S=\left\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2: -3\le x\le 3,\, x\le y\le \sqrt{9-x^2}\right\}$$  and 
$$S’=\left\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2: \frac 3{\sqrt 2}\le x\le 3,\, \sqrt{9-x^2}\le y\le x\right\}.$$

The correspondence between Cartesian coordinates $(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2$ and polar 
coordinates $(r,\varphi)\in\Bbb R^+\times [0,2\pi)$ is $x=r\cos\varphi $, 
$y=r\sin\varphi$, $$S=\{(r,\varphi): 0\le r\le 3,\, \pi/4\le \varphi\le \pi\}\cup$$ 
$$\{(r,\varphi): 0\le r\le - 3/\cos\varphi,\, \pi\le \varphi\le 5\pi/4\},$$
$$S’=\{(r,\varphi): 3\le r\le 3/\cos\varphi,\, 0\le \varphi\le \pi/4\},$$

and $dS=r dr d\varphi$. Thus

$$\int_S x^2y dx dy=\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi}\int_0^3 r^4\cos^2\varphi\sin\varphi dr d\varphi+$$
$$\int_{\pi}^{5\pi/4}\int_0^{-3/\cos\varphi} r^4\cos^2\varphi\sin\varphi dr d\varphi-
\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\int_0^{3/\cos\varphi} r^4\cos^2\varphi\sin\varphi dr d\varphi.$$

*References*

[Fich] Grigoriy Fichtenholz, *Differential and Integral Calculus*, v. III, 4-th edition, Moscow: Nauka, 1966, (in Russian).

Comment: wrong answer -1  , try to improve , your answer = $+\frac{81}{5\sqrt2}$

Comment: @learningstudent Thanks. Fixed.

Comment: So you're looking at the points inside this circle with angles between $\frac\pi4$ and $\frac\pi2$. How do you get that? It should be the angles between $\frac\pi4$ and $\frac {5\pi}{4}$.

Comment: @zhw. My [first impression](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/3704326/1) about the integration domain was the same as in your answer, but it turned out to be wrong, and, as pointed learningstudent above, provided a wrong value of the integral. A correct situation is shown at the picture in Quanto’s [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3696544/converting-cartesian-to-polar-double-integral/3705788#3705788).

Comment: Remark that when $\frac 3{\sqrt 2}<x\le 3$, the upper bound of the integral $\int_x^\sqrt{9-x^2} x^2y dy$ is smaller than the lower bound, so the sign of the integral has to be inverted for this part of the integration domain, that is when $0\le\varphi<\pi/4$, and I considered this part of the domain separately. Also when $x\le 0$, and $y$ is *any* real number between $x$ and $0$ (not necessarily satisfying $x^2+y^2\le 3$), a point $(x,y)$ belongs to the integration domain.

Comment: By this reason I considered the part of the integration domain when $x,y\le 0$ (that is, when $\pi\le\varphi\le 5\pi/4$) separately too.

Comment: @AlexRavsky Thanks for your comment. Yes, I completely missed the point of this one.

Answer (score 1):

For $x\le y \le \sqrt{9-x^2}$ we get the points inside the circle $x^2+y^2=3^2$ (with radius equal to $3$) and above the line $y=x$. So you're looking at the points inside this circle with angles between $\frac\pi4$ and $\frac\pi2$. (The angle $\pi/4$ corresponds to the points on the line $y=x$.)

We need the points which are below the line and outside of the circle. The second integral is with negative sign, since with positive sign we would get the integral from $\sqrt{9-x^2}$ to $x$.

$$\int_0^3 \int_{x}^{\sqrt{9-x^2}} x^2y dy dx=
\int_{\frac\pi4}^\frac\pi2  \int_0^3 r^4 \cos^2\theta\sin\theta dr d\theta-
\int_0^{\frac\pi4}  \int_3^{3/\cos\theta} r^4 \cos^2\theta\sin\theta dr d\theta.$$

(For the integral on the LHS [WolframAlpha returns $-\frac{81}{10}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_0%5E3+%5Cint_%7Bx%7D%5E%7B%5Csqrt%7B9-x%5E2%7D%7D+x%5E2y+dy+dx). On the RHS we get [this integral](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+r%5E4+cos%5E2%28a%29+sin%28a%29+for+a%3Dpi%2F4+to+pi%2F2%2C+r%3D0+to+3+) and [this integral](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+r%5E4+cos%5E2%28a%29+sin%28a%29+for+a%3D0+to+pi%2F4%2C+r%3D3+to+3%2F%28cos%28a%29%29), they together give us $\frac{81}{10}(\frac1{\sqrt2}-\frac{2+\sqrt2}2)=-\frac{81}{10}$.)

This returns only the part of integral for $x\ge0$. <s>But since the whole integral is symmetric, you can then multiply this by the factor of two to get the integral from the original problem.</s> We can multiply this by the factor of two to get the integral
$$\int_{-3}^3 \int_{|x|}^{\sqrt{9-x^2}} x^2y dy dx.$$
We're still missing this part:
$$\int_{-3}^0 \int_{x}^{-x} x^2y dy dx.$$
However, this integral will be zero since $\int_x^{-x} ydy=\left[\frac{y^2}2\right]_x^{-x}=0.$

Comment: @learningstudent I suppose this part corresponds to the part between the circle and the vertical line: $\int\limits_{0}^{\pi/4}\int\limits_{3/\cos \theta}^{3\sqrt2}r^4\cos^2 \theta \sin \theta dr d\theta$. Shouldn't then the lower bound be $3$ (points on the circle) and the upper bound $3/\cos\theta$ (points on the vertical line $x=3$)?

Comment: @learningstudent With positive sign, I would get an integral which corresponds to $\int_{\sqrt{9-x^2}}^x \dots dy$. If I want $\int_x^{\sqrt{9-x^2}}$, I need the negative sign. (Notice that in this area we have $\sqrt{9-x^2}<x$.

Comment: what about the region from pi/2 to 5pi/4 ??